# How to get the text of an element as the web shows?

Tags: python, html, selenium, text, getattribute

Im doing some scrapping with selenium Python, my problem is that, when I call WebElement.text() it gives me a string in one line with no format. But I want to get that text just as the web shows, that is, with the line breaks.

For example, the element with text:

```
<br>'Hello this is an example'<br>
```

In  the web it shows as:

```
<br>
'Hello this is an<br> 
example'
```

I want the second result, but Selenium gives me the first one. I tried to 'manually' give format to the text using the width of the words with PIL, but the results are quite unexact.

Comment: "just as the web shows" - your *browser* shows it. How it does may depend on a lot of things, including for example the size of your browser window. So, how lines get broken is mostly not part of the HTML.

Comment: Well, then I should look for another solution, thanks!!

Comment: How does the DOM shows the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the [*text*](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute, you need to use the [*get_attribute("innerHTML")*](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) as follows:

```
print(WebElement.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55241232/7429447)

---

### References

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55902072/7429447)